# How to tell parent to pop current modal and redirect to NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin application, where my `MainPage` is a navigationpage (contentpage). In this navigationpage I open modals.

In the modals I open in my MainPage, I want to use `Navigation.PushAsync` but this requires the NavigationPage context which a modal page is not.

I've read that the flow would be:

1. Tell parent/caller to pop current visible modal
2. Tell parent/caller
   to navigate to the page I want, using `Navigation.PushAsync`

However, how do you do this? How do you tell the parent to do this and actually do the navigation?

Comment: You should be able to do this at modal level using `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation`. Recommended way would be to create a couple extension methods to INavigation and [access context through dependency service or your app's DI container](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use event handlers to get this job done:

Here is an example code:
App.cs

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PushedNavigationPage());
    }    

}
```

PushedNavigationPage Page:

```
public class PushedNavigationPage: ContentPage
{       

   public PusehdNavigationPage()
   {


   }        

   public void DoPushModalOnButtonClick()
   {
      var pushedModalPage = new PushedModalPage();
      pushedModalPage.DoPush += HandleDoPush;
      Navigation.PushModalAsync(pushedModalPage);
   }

   private void HandleDoPush(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Navigation.PopModalAsync();
       Navigation.PushAsync(//the page you want to push)
   }
}
```

PushedModalPage

```
public class PushedModalPage : ContentPage
{
   public event EventHandler DoPush;  
    //call this on putton click or whenever you want
    private void OnDoPush()
    {
        if (DoPush!= null)
        {
            DoPush(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }     
}
```

I have not awaiting the async methods but it is better to do so and this is just an example, but I think you should get the idea..